# Port sweep with python

Tags: python, for-loop, networking, ping

Well im trying to do something really simpale but from some reason i just can't understand how to do it.

Im trying to write a simple port sweep
let's say i have a gateway address of 192.168.1.1 all i want to do is to create a for loop to run between 1 to 254 and test what ip address there are over the network

The for loop is really easy:

```
for i in range(1,254,1):
```

I need that i will change everytime at 192.168.1.i

How can i do that?

Comment: Why not use nmap?

Comment: @shuttle87 just want to practice python

Comment: How would you do it for a single IP address? How would you create an IP address from an integer for the 4th byte? How would you create IP addresses in a loop? Put it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Use string formatting to accomplish that

```
'192.168.1.{0}'.format(i)
```

Or be a brute and do concatenation

```
'192.168.1.' + str(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way of doing this in the standard library:

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> for addr in ipaddress.IPv4Network('192.168.1.0/24'):
...     print(addr)
192.168.1.0
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
#more addresses
192.168.1.254
192.168.1.255
```